# Cast from B to base class A

Tags: c++, casting, operator-keyword, radix, derived

I have the following classes:

```
template<typename T>
class Vector { ... };

template<typename T>
class Vector2 : public Vector<T> { ... };
```

Now, i would like to be able to cast a Vector to a Vector2 -even if the object is not really a Vector2- (I mean, dynamic_cast is not what I'm looking for)

What should I implement?

1. the cast operator on Vector  `operator Vector2 ()`
2. the constructor on Vector2 `Vector2(const Vector<T> &)`
3. both

If i should implement both, when will the cast operator, and when the constructor be calld?

Comment: Didn't we have this question yesterday? `class Dog : public Animal {};`. Now, how to turn all animals into dogs?

Comment: It wasn't phrased that way, but it is the same question. If you want to convert an array or vector from one type to another, you have to make a new copy. There are no tricks, and casting `(Dog*)&Cat` just doesn't work.

Comment: Out of curiousity, what's the rationale for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would implement an explicit constructor `Vector2` that takes a `Vector<U>` -- since you might want to use unrelated types that can be converted from one to another.

```
template <typename T>
class Vector2 : public Vector< T >
{
public:
    template <typename U>
    explicit Vector2(const Vector< U >& copyFrom)
    {
        // ...
    }
};
```

Implicit convertion might lead to unpredictable behaviors. *Kids, don't try this at home*.

Answer (score 2):

You want to **cast a Vector to a Vector2 - even if the object is not really a Vector2**? You really can't do that without making a new copy. You could do this:

```
class Vector2 { public: void test() {} };

Vector foo;
Vector2* bad = reinterpret_cast<Vector2*>(&foo);

bad->test();
```

But then you'll just be calling methods based on the offsets defined by the `Vector2` class. You can cast any class to `Vector2` pointer like this if it pleases you, but don't expect anything to work.

```
int stackInteger = 42;
Vector2* reallyBad = reinterpret_cast<Vector2*>(&stackInteger);

reallyBad->test();
```